# window.gameEngine in tictactoe.html?

Tags: chromecast, tic-tac-toe

In Google's GitHub resources, there's a 'TicTacToe' receiver. In the tictactoe.html file, on line 38, there's this line:
    window.gameEngine = new cast.TicTacToe(mBoard);

I'm trying to understand what exactly 'gameEngine' is. It's not referenced anywhere else in the code, or other files. Could someone help explain the purpose of putting the TicTacToe object in 'gameEngine'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is creating a new instance of cast.TicTacToe and assigning that to window.gameEngine so later on it can be accessed from anywhere needed.

Comment: I understand that. I don't understand why, because gameEngine isn't referenced again in the code.

Comment: Thats is correct, it is not used elsewhere, so you can drop the assignment and just instantiate the TicTacToe object.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And the reason they chose to put it with the window object, was so that it could be referenced to anywhere else?